# React Props not passing down to children components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I am trying to learn React so please bear with me!

I am following a tutorial to help me understand react and how you can pass down components.

I am trying to pass props down 2 levels, but when I render the code on the third element, nothing appears on the page. Using React Dev tools on chrome, it seems that the props are loading on the Tweets.js component rather than the Tweet.js component.

Can anybody tell me whats wrong? The order is App.js > Tweets.js > Tweet.js

For ref, I am following the following tutorial, it is around the 15 min mark.
[React State and Props | Learn React For Beginners Part 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMH1_YtUTSQ&t=476s)

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Tweets from './components/Tweets';

import React from 'react';

function App() {
    const name=["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"];
    const age=["21", "22", "24"]; /* Data is created here */

    return ( 
        <div className="App">
            <Tweets me={name} age={age} />{/*Data is added to component*/ }  
        </div>
        
    );
}
export default App;
```

Tweets.js

```
import Tweet from './Tweet';

const Tweets = (props) => (
    <section>
        <Tweet /> 
    </section>
);



export default Tweets;
```

Tweet.js

```
const Tweet = (props) => (
    <div>
        <h1>{props.me}</h1>
        <h1>{props.age}</h1>
    </div>
);



export default Tweet;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to transfer props through your `Tweets` component:

```
const Tweets = (props) => (
    <section>
        <Tweet {...props} /> 
    </section>
);
```

Comment: Hi there, Just tried it, didn't work and got an error.
src\components\Tweets.js 
Syntax error: Unexpected token (6:16), it points at the "." in "...props"

Comment: you need to surround props with curly brackets {...props} could not edit the post because is less that 6 characters.

Comment: Okay yeah that worked, also, I updated the thread with the tutorial I am watching. The coder is using the exact same code I am and his works and mines doesn't, why is that?